# Multiple docker instance for multiple client

Tags: docker, deployment

I am doing containerisation of some legacy application (web + service + C++ app) which runs on Linux environment and currently has more than 10 clients.

I could set up and run the app (C++ app) from Docker. Since the app is going to read some property file which will be different for different clients. So I tried to mount drive for sharing data outside of Docker (runtime some files may got changed).

But my biggest concern is how do I run a single container for different clients whose runtime (in memory state) will be different? (Application will run forever, until someone kills/stops it).

Do I need to run *n* containers for *n* clients?

Does Docker swarm/Kubernetes have some property for such a scenario?

Will ech client get its own dedicated container?

Can you suggest also some further reading/studying for such scenarios?

And for the Database - since every client will have different data - different DB should be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate containers by supplying them with a unique name and environment variables.

Example:

```
docker run --name client1 --env-file ./client1.env your-image-name-here
```

You can have isolated environments and configurations which is unique for each context respectively with this approach.

You need N containers for N clients. But you can use same image for N containers. So one container per customer and each container will be identified by it's own unique name and environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

What you make sound like your basic needs are :

- same application for everyone
- one configuation per client
- one DB per client

The first point is easy to solive : "**same application = same image**".

Then, what you'll need to personalize the application will be configuration and DB path.
If you want to containerize the DB, the questions will be the same, to let's say you have a DB url instead (it could could be a container : it doesn't matter that much).

There are various options to personnalize your applications :

- inherit from the common image and decline it in as many images as you need... with a serious impact on maintenability
- add customisation through "[docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)", which is easier to read, write and maintain!

If one instance per client is ok, just go with a docker-compose per client.
If you happen to need more, go for swarm mode (you can use swarm mode for one instance as well).

In both cases, you'll need a docker-compose (actually you don't really NEED it since you can do all the same through command line, but it's less easy to maintain to my opov, and less easy to explain!).

It may look like that :

```
version: "3.7"

my-service:
   image: your/common/image:1.0
   volume:
      - /a/path/from/host/with/confs:/a/path/to/container/conf/dir # will replace content there!
   environment:
      - "DB_URL=my-cny.denver.com:3121/db_client" # can vary or be the same if DB_NAME vary instead
      - "DB_NAME=my-cny.denver.com:3121/db_client_1" #vary the name of the DB
      - "DB_PSSWD=toto"
 ...
```

There are things you shouldn't do, such as writing clear PWD here, but that's just an example.

There are better mecanisms for config file and sensitive data that should be managed though "[config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#configs)" and "secret" [mecanisms](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets).